# Will Postgres' DISTINCT function always return null as the first element?

Tags: postgresql

I'm selecting distinct values from tables thru Java's JDBC connector and it seems that NULL value (if there's any) is always the first row in the ResultSet.

I need to remove this NULL from the List where I load this ResultSet. The logic looks only at the first element and if it's null then ignores it.

I'm not using any ORDER BY in the query, can I still trust that logic? I can't find any reference in Postgres' documentation about this.

Comment: Show us the table definitions and the query. But in general if you do not use an `order by` you can **not** rely on any order of the returned data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not stated in the manual, I wouldn't trust it. However, just for fun and try to figure out what logic is being used, running the following query does bring the NULL (for no apparent reason) to the top, while all other values are in an apparent random order:

```
with t(n) as (values (1),(2),(1),(3),(null),(8),(0)) 
select distinct * from t
```

However, cross joining the table with a modified version of itself brings two NULLs to the top, but random NULLs dispersed througout the resultset. So it doesn't seem to have a clear-cut logic clumping all NULL values at the top.

```
with t(n) as (values (1),(2),(1),(3),(null),(8),(0)) 
select distinct * from t 
cross join (select n+3 from t) t2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check for NOT NULL. Simply like

```
select distinct columnName 
from Tablename    
where columnName IS NOT NULL
```

Also if you are not providing the ORDER BY clause then then order in which you are going to get the result is not guaranteed, hence you can not rely on it. So it is better and recommended to provide the ORDER BY clause if you want your result output in a particular output(*i.e., ascending or descending*)

If you are looking for a [reference Postgresql document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) then it says:

> If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the
>   system finds fastest to produce.

Comment: I'm working on old hardware and I wanted to access this data with the smallest cost possible; no ORDER, no WHERE condition. NULL at as the first row also spared me an iteration. Or not, as I see now.

Comment: @AdamHorvath: reducing the number of rows that are returned will be less expensive then returning unnecessary data. Especially because the `where` is evaluated _before_ the `distinct` so by reducing the rows the `distinct` has less work to do. The cost of the select with or without that `where` clause will essentially be the same. If you have an index on the column it will even _improve_ the performance.